# Problem with redirect in htaccess wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following redirects in htaccess Wordpress is installed in home folder The site must redirect an example.com (without www) and with https
The wordpress installation is in / home

And I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions? Thank you !!

````
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ home/index.php [L]

# BEGIN SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>

 # END SSL```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force subfolder or subdomain to redirect to https

for https redirection just use this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For Subfolder

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/home/$1 [R,L]
```

also you can use the default .htaccess for redirection

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```