# .htaccess - Redirect not working for Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have this RewriteRule Here:

```
RewriteRule ^TWI$ https://www.paypal.com
```

But its not working, basically what I am trying to do is have a page like so https://example.com/TWI redirect to paypal's website. What am I doing wrong? Here are are rest of my rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^TWI$ https://www.paypal.com
</IfModule>
```

Comment: check this resource https://wpscholar.com/blog/simple-redirects-with-htaccess/ and use https://www.htaccessredirect.net/ to create htaccess rules. I use this whenever necessary, really helpful tool i must say. Hope this works.

Comment: I tried Redirect 301 "/TWI" "https://www.paypal.com" didn't work

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324629/problem-with-redirect-in-htaccess-wordpress/57324856#57324856

Comment: Redirect 301 /TWI/ https://www.paypal.com

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the order of the rules, please check:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^TWI$ https://www.paypal.com [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```